# Problems with my LoginActivity code

Tags: java, android-studio

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKCdqCuFFFk

I completed the tutorial, but when I wanted to launch, it gave an error. These are my codes:

(MainActivity.java)

```
    package com.example.admir_000.jdsfnjls;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView tvRegisterHere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);
        registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admir_000.jdsfnjls.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Register here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterHere" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Username" />

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's always a great idea to include your logcat error.

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, without read the logcat, that you got a **Null Pointer Exception**.... why?

```
registerLink.setOnClickListener....
```

Where did you initialized registerLink variable? Maybe you wanted to put **tvRegisterHere.setOnClickListener**...

P.S: I suggest you to already read the stacktrace and then search for the particular Exception